# Episerver - How to Manage Media Items on Multiple Environments

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-8

Hi guys I'm working on an exiting Episerver project (my first one) -

One of the issues that we are having is we have three enviroments for our episerver website. Developer / Staging / Live.

All have sepreate DBs. At the moment, we have had lots of media items added to our live enviroment via the CMS, we want to sync this with our staging enviroment.

However when we use the export data feature from live admin section and try to restore it to our staging enviroment, we end up with missing media, duplicate folders etc.

Is there a tool/plugin avalible to manage content/media across mulitple enviroments. Umbraco has something called "courier" (Umbraco being another CMS I have used in the past) looking for the episerver equvilent.

Or is the best way to do this export the live SQL database and over write my staging one? We have diffrent user permissions set in these enviroments how can we manage that?

How is this genreally done in the world of episerver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the most common way to handle this is as you say to do it manually. Restore the db, copy the fileshare, and set up the access rights on the stage environment after the restore.

Answer (score 0):

Luc made a nice provider for keeping your local environment in sync. https://devblog.gosso.se/2017/09/downloadifmissingfileblob-provider-version-1-6-for-episerver/